# Recursively print a tree structure of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, tree

so I'm looking for some help on programming a function like the one described in the images below. I'll post the code for the provided function and also post what I have worked on so far.

[Assignment description part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0j2H.png)

[Assignment Desciption part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7XUq.png)

Provided function:

```
def print_file_listing(file_listing, indent=""):
"""Format and print file_listing, a dictionary representing the
description of a disk file.

Parameters:

    file_listing:  a dictionary with keys "name", "timestamp",
        "type" and "size".  The "type" value (always "file") is
        omitted from the printed output.

    indent (optional):  a string of spaces representing the
        level at which the file is nested in the folder
        structure.
"""
print(f"{indent}{file_listing['name']:<12} "\
      f"{file_listing['timestamp']} "\
      f"{file_listing['size']:>8}")
```

My code so far:

```
def print_folder(folder, indent="0"):
"""Format and print folder, a dictionary representing a file
system.

Parameters:

    folder:  a dictionary with keys "name", "timestamp", "type" and
        "files".  "files" is a list of zero or more files and
        folders.  The "type" value (always "dir") is omitted from
        the printed output.

    indent (optional):  a string of spaces representing the
        level at which the folder is nested in the file system.
"""
print(f"{indent}{folder['name']:<12} {folder['timestamp']}")
if(folder['type']=='dir'):
    for checksubDir in (folder['files']):#handles sub directories
        print_folder(checksubDir, indent+1)
if(folder['type']=='file'):
    for s in range(0,indent):#looping for spaces
        print(' ')
        print_file_listing(folder)
```

`def main():
    root = json_reader.read_json('dir_tree_1.json')
    print_folder(root)

main()
`

Comment: [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the actual problem? "I am looking for help on homework" is not a question...

Answer (score -1):

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Please, use comments if you are trying to gain clarification on the question.